# Two same AJAX calls - one is working, other doesn't

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, headers

I am developing a WP plugin. I have two same AJAX calls, one is working, and second one is giving me 400 Bad Request error for admin-ajax.php.

ReadyState is 4, responseText is: "
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵0", statusText is "Bad Request", error is `POST http://localhost/wc_addtocart_as_admin/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)`

Both calls are getting data from two separated `<form>` elements. When I change `data` in working AJAX to use array defined in js code, like in example below, it gives me the same error like the second AJAX call which is not working at all.

```
    var test = [];
            test[0] = {name: "reason", value: 'OLALA'};
            test[1] = {name: "second", value: 'TRUS'};

    jQuery.ajax({
                url: test_ajax_object.ajax_url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: test

                etc...

                })
```

So, only first AJAX works with first `<form>` data. And second one, which is absolutely the same, doesn't.

What could be possible reasons for this weird behavior? Please let me know if I should provide some more info.

[image: Headers difference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're not the same though. Look at the form data on each one. The second one, the one that doesn't work, has `_test` appended to the parameter names and the action value.

The reason you're getting a 400 error is because you're not sending a valid `action`. The `action` parameter is how WordPress determines which callback to use to handle the request. If you don't send `action` with a valid value, no callback exists to handle the request and it returns a 400 error.

You need to make sure the parameter is called `action`, not `action_test`, and the value is the proper name you're using in PHP. In your case that appears to be `return_reason`, not `return_reason_test`.

Comment: I assumed and key names and values in associative array I am sending through AJAX are arbitrary. But on my second thought, yes, I am aware that action value must equal to wp_ajax_{name}, and that form must have it's "action", but somehow I forgot that. Probably because I was too tired. Thanks for your answer.